# Using a mouse with two PCs

Tags: windows, keyboard, mouse

One running Windows 7, the other Ubuntu. I would like to use my laptops (windows) keyboard and an external mouse (wireless, dongle) to be able to control both. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an OSS solution to this called Synergy.  It allows you to control multiple computers with a single keyboard and mouse so long as they are networked.  It supports Windows, Linux and Mac.  More details here: http://synergy-project.org/

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note: Only 13.04 has version 1.4+ in the repositories. You either need to install a newer package via PPA or download, or install a 1.3 version on the Windows machine to get it working with older Ubuntu releases.